# Add a new parameter on URL after the last slash or the last word of the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add "/finished" on my URL when click on button withou reloading the page or if it's not possible the "/", only "-finished".

My URL is: www.myname.com/firstparemeter/secondparameter**/finished**

So, the script must add after the last "/" or only add a "-finished" on the last word of the URL.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnclick').click(function () {
         window.location.hash = '/finished';
    });

});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="btn-submit" id="btnclick" onclick="IsEmpty();" />
```

Can you guys help me? I'm begineer

Comment: This has been asked many times, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Totally different sir.

Comment: Both answers in this thread are the second answer in the one linked above.

Answer (score 1):

```
history.pushState({}, "", window.location.hash + "/finished")
```

It could be window.location.href as well

Comment: Its working with the window.location.href, but when already has one "/" it's adding one more "//". It's there a way to verify if already has one "/"?

Comment: Maybe i can add something like that; clean_url = abc.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");

Comment: you can check if window.location.href.slice(-1) == '/'

Answer (score 0):

```
history.pushState({}, '', '/finished')
```

Comment: It's working, but it cancel all the parameters before the last slash /.
My url is: www.myname.com/parameter1/parameter2/finished

Comment: Can you describe this solution in more detail? How does it solve the problem?